# Access properties of elements defined in ControlTemplate in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in my xaml I have to put 10 items defined as:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
  <TextBox Width="100"
           DataContext="{StaticResource dataProvider}"
           Text="{Binding XPath='BLOCK[@id=2]/ITEMS/ITEM[@id=1]/@value'}"/>
  <ComboBox Margin="5" 
            DataContext="{StaticResource dataProvider}"
            SelectedValuePath="Tag"
            SelectedValue="{Binding XPath='BLOCK[@id=2]/ITEMS/ITEM[@id=2]/@value'}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="GROUP" Tag="6" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="PRIVATE" Tag="5" />
  </ComboBox>            
  <TextBox Width="200"
           DataContext="{StaticResource dataProvider}"
           Text="{Binding XPath='BLOCK[@id=2]/ITEMS/ITEM[@id=4]/@value'}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

So, instead of repeat it many times, I thought to use a ControlTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="AddressItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox Name="Address" Width="200"/>
      <ComboBox Name="Type">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="GROUP" Tag="6" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="PRIVATE" Tag="5" />
      </ComboBox>
      <TextBox Name="Description" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>      
</DataTemplate.Resources>
```

Now when I use it...

```
<Control Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource AddressItemTemplate}" />
<Control Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource AddressItemTemplate}" />
<Control Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource AddressItemTemplate}" />
```

.. since the XPath binding property is different for each item (the ITEM[@Id] changes always), I need a way to access the TextBox.Text, ComboBox.SelectedValuePath and ComboBox.SelectedValue property when I create the 'Control'.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common question in WPF. You can access these elements if you named your `Control` `control` like this:

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)control.Template.FindName("Address", control);

ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)control.Template.FindName("Type", control);
```

I trust that you can work the rest out for yourself.

Comment: Hi @sheridan, thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I need a way to access these props inside the same xaml file and not from code.

Comment: Then the answer is 'no, you can't do that'. You'll just need to declare several `ControlTemplate` objects or a `UserControl` where you expose those properties as `Dependency Properties`... *then* you'll be able to bind to them from your `UserControl`.