# Binding Parent's property to child's readonly property

Tags: wpf, xaml

### Hello!

I am creating a custom control `MyControl`, using `Zoombox` control from Extended WPF Toolkit. `Zoombox` has a `Viewport` property. I created the same property `MyViewport` in `MyControl` and I need to bind it to `Zoombox`'s `Viewport` property. I could bind from `Zoombox` to `MyControl`, but `Viewport` in `Zoombox` is defined as `readonly DependencyProperty`. I know two ways to do that (listed below), but I would like to avoid them.

---

### Two ways of doing it

1. Access `Zoombox` from code-behind using `FindTemplate` and its name.
2. Edit `Zoombox` source code and add a setter to `Viewport`.

---

### Generic.xaml file of `MyControl`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControlLibrary"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                    <xctk:Zoombox x:Name="PART_Zoombox"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="MyViewport"
                Value={Binding ElementName=PART_Zoombox, Path=Viewport}
        />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So, how can I do it using only XAML?

Comment: Zoombox.Viewport is a read-only property that is internally updated by the Zoombox control. You can't simply set it.

Comment: That is why I am trying to bind my property **to** it, I am not trying to change `Zoombox` `Viewport` property.

Comment: Then what stops you from doing that? A readonly dependency property can of course be used as the source property of a binding.

Comment: `Zoombox` is a child of `MyControl`. I do not know the markup to bind `MyControl.MyViewport` property to `Zoombox.Viewport` property.

Comment: There is no such markup. You would usually call `Template.FindName("PART_Zoombox")` to get the Zoombox in code behind. See e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18614227/1136211).

Comment: That said, it would of course work in the XAML of a UserControl, where you would not have a ControlTemplate.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The point of my answer was to ensure, that there is no way to do it, other than using code-behind. Thanks for the input. :)